# Odd python error - code in stack trace doesn't match up with actual file

Tags: python

Here's what I had in my file (line 94):

```
desktop = {k[0]:(v[0]/v[1]) for k,v in mymap.items() if k[1] == 'f'}
```

Here's what running this code from the command line spit out:

```
File "process.py", line 94
    desktop = {[0]k:(v[0]/v[1]) for k,v in ctr_map.items() if k[1] == 'f'}
                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Odd, right?  For laughs, I changed the original line to match the line in the error (hoping that two swaps make a right), and I got:

```
File "process.py", line 94
    desktop = {00kk:(v[0]/v[1]) for k,v in ctr_map.items() if k[1] == 'f'}
                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Then, I deleted all pyc files from the directory (there was no process.pyc, but there was one for another file loaded by process) and it worked!  I suppose I'm looking more for an explanation than for a fix.  I have not been able to reproduce (yet!).

This happened for both pypy (first), and then regular python.
Version information:

```
Python 2.7.1+ (r271:86832, Sep 27 2012, 21:12:17) 
[GCC 4.5.2] on linux2

Python 2.7.2 (0e28b379d8b3, Feb 09 2012, 19:41:03)
[PyPy 1.8.0 with GCC 4.4.3] on linux2
```

Comment: `dict comprehension` should work fine in Python 2.7.1.

Comment: What does `python -c "import sys;print sys.version"` returns?

Comment: @hcwsa the same information as given in my question

Comment: My first guess would be that the `.pyc` file created by one Python wasn't readable by the other. For example, maybe you have a wide-Unicode 2.7 and a narrow-Unicode 2.x that think they can share compiled files but actually can't. Or a 64-bit and 32-bit. Or… any of the things that Python 3.x distinguishes in its pyc cache directories that 2.x didn't distinguish that led to bugs like this.

Comment: It also could just be a bug in PyPy 1.8 that's long since been fixed. (The pace of development is pretty rapid, and the fact that I can't repro anything similar in 2.1 doesn't prove anything unless we go back and look through all of the fixes between 1.8 and 2.1 and make sure none of them seem relevant…)